# Background image not displaying for email in html

Tags: html, html-email

I am creating a template for email contains a background. It is visible in browser not in mail.

```
<tr>
  <td  colspan="2">
     <table style="width:195px;background: url(coupon_bg%20.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <tr>
           <td style="border-right: white 1px solid;padding-bottom: 5px; "><span style="font-size: 20px;" ><b>40%</b></span><br />discount</td>
           <td style="padding-left: 10px;"> code <br>XXXXX</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 10px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 15px;">Our new update would give parents an opportunity to learn a lot more about their children's performance at school.</td>
</tr>
```

width of outer tr 545px,table with 195px, actual image width 190px, last td width 348px

Comment: How are you including the image file in the email?

Comment: I did the same in this template in different place that's work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the email is received out from the domain of your site, `url(coupon_bg%20.png)` returns an incomplete path. It should point to a fully qualified path, e.g: `http://foo.org/path/to/image`.

**EDIT**

Also beware of space characters in file names. `coupon_bg%20.png` means that the source file name must be "coupon_bg .png" (notice the space character before the dot).

Comment: I did the same in this template in different place with another image that's work fine.

Comment: Does the image's file name really have a space character before the '.png' suffix?

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking your code in your browser your image path is correct. But when you will send the code in email image path will be different. So put full image path in code